# interaction between jquery and php using GET

Tags: php, jquery

I want to write a web page and use jquery to GET a small amount of data from php at the server, but in the same file, when i click a button.  I want to send ?nm=bill and answer with 'bob'. i press the button but it doesn't seem to arrive at the server.  I get the contents of the file i am sending the query to. I clear the browser, firefox, history before i press the button. Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// --- embed the call in btn by id ---
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    console.log("btn pressed");
    $.get("a_foo.php?nm=bill", function(data, status){
      alert("Data:\n" + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$rsp = "7 come 11";
?>

<button id="btn">Send</button>

<p id="rch"><?php echo $rsp; ?> </p> 

<body>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){
  var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);
  if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
    echo "bob";
  }
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but in the same file

So all of the code shown is in one file?  If that's the case then any request to that file is going to receive the entire response.

> I get the contents of the file i am sending the query to.

That's expected behavior.  The very first thing this file does is emit all of the HTML at the start.  Then it executes some PHP and conditionally emits a single value at the end.

Putting these things into *separate* files would be the ideal approach.  One file is the UI, the other file is the service that handles the AJAX request and returns just the expected data.

But if you really want them to be in the same file then you'd need to conditionally return all of that HTML.  Since the only difference between the requests at this time is whether or not a query string is present then your whole PHP file would look something like:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
    echo "bob";
} else {
/>
    <!-- ALL of your other HTML goes here -->
<?php
}
?>
```

As you can probably imagine, this structure gets pretty ugly and difficult to maintain pretty fast.  Which is why the preferred approach is to separate these things into their own files.  Each PHP file would do just the one thing it needs to do, rather than having one big PHP file which conditionally does multiple different things.

Answer (score 0):

The current target of request is a_foo.php i fix it and show bob if the get nm is bill else show html

```
<?php
$_nm = $_GET["nm"];
if($_nm == "bill"){
    echo "bob";
}
else
{
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// --- embed the call in btn by id ---
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        console.log("btn pressed");
        $.get("?nm=bill", function(data, status){
          alert("Data:\n" + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$rsp = "7 come 11";
?>
<button id="btn">Send</button>
<p id="rch"><?php echo $rsp; ?> </p> 
<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```